# PHP code when it come to sending a mail to different parties depending on the radio button selection

Tags: php

I don't really understand PHP and now I need to make our contact us for information form go to a different email address depending on their campus selection.

The page can be found on http://www.aisj-jhb.com/Admissions/ContactUs.html

If they select Johannesburg campus the mail goes to a different person and if they select Pretoria Campus the mail goes to someone else.  I know it is something to do with the parameters, but once more it is greek or code to me.

Here is a extract from the code.  Note I didn't do the original PHP code, but can edit it slightly.

```
$siteaddress ="http://www.aisj-jhb.com"; 
$sitename = "AISJ"; 
$EmailFrom = "AISJ"; 
$EmailTo = "lvdalen@aisj-jhb.com";
$Subject = "AISJ-Requesting Information";
```

Now I know my email addresses go into the `$EmailTo = section.`

Can someone please help me with the parameters?

Thank you

Liesl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Try it and let's see.

```
   $siteaddress ="http://www.aisj-jhb.com"; 
   $sitename = "AISJ"; 
   $EmailFrom = "AISJ"; 
   $Subject = "AISJ-Requesting Information"; 
   switch($_POST["Campus"]){
      case "Johannesburg":
      $EmailTo = johannesburg@aisj-jhb.com;
      case "Pretoria":
      $EmailTo = pretoria@aisj-jhb.com;
      default: //In case neither radio button is selected
      $EmailTo = lvdalen@aisj-jhb.com;
   };
```

**Edit:** Switch case helps to control the flow process based on what the posted value of the radio button "campus" is. In Case its Johannesburg, send to the Jo'burg mail. In case its pretoria, do similarly. If neither of the two, send to lvdalen.

Meanwhile, you can also edit this to ensure that the person selects one or the other:

```
<input type="radio" value="Johannesburg" name="Campus" checked="checked">
```

Comment: I did this, but the Pretoria campus information isn't reaching the specified e-mail.  I do get the e-mail stating that my information has been submitted when I test it, but the information is lost in space.  The Johannesburg info reaches the right e-mail.  There are no errors in the code... What am I still doing wrong?  Also I don't need a default email as they have to select either Johannesburg or Pretoria otherwise the form will not go out.  Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: This is the code:                                             $siteaddress ="http://www.aisj-jhb.com"; 
$sitename = "AISJ"; 
$EmailFrom = "AISJ"; 
switch($_POST["Campus"]){
 case "Johannesburg Campus":
 $EmailTo = "lvdalen@aisj-jhb.com"; "lsteinbrucker@aisj-jhb.com";
 case "Pretoria Campus":
 $EmalTo = "lsteinbrucker@aisj-jhb.com"; "lvdalen@aisj-jhb.com";};
$Subject = "AISJ-Requesting Information";

Comment: Note that the information for Johannesburg only went to my email and not to the second person.

Comment: Two things, Liesl. No, three. (1) For Pretoria, you wrote "EmalTo" rather than "EmailTo". Thus the email will never reach Pretoria. (2) Remove that last line i.e. the one after Pretoria's email. Since you dont need a default case, it shouldnt be there. (3) I would have advised you to remove those email addresses for confidentiality, but it's too late to edit your comments I guess.

Comment: Thank you, I would hug you if you were closer... so be glad.  IT WORKS :)  you rock big time.

Comment: know some of the people are saying they don't receive the information.  The code is as you said: switch($_POST["Campus"]){
 case "Johannesburg Campus":
 $EmailTo = "email01@aisj-jhb.com, email02@aisj-jhb.com, email03@aisj-jhb.com";
 case "Pretoria Campus":
 $EmailTo = "email04@aisj-jhb.com, email03@aisj-jhb.com";
 };   Email03 is for control reasons receiving both campuses emails.  Email03 did receive the recent JHB email test.  Is there anything wrong with my code, I don't have any syntax errors.

Comment: Hi Liesl. It appears your PHP Mailing script may be at fault because the code above seems perfect. Can you paste the mailer code as an edit to your post above, or on pastebin.com or something so that I can check it out?

Comment: // send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=ok.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}

Comment: I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: Hi Liesl, Im just getting this. I think I see what the problem is. You have placed a space in the value of your radio item i.e. "Johannesburg Campus" and when this is submitted, the space will be converted to %20% due to character encoding i.e. "Johannesburg%20%Campus". Dont use a space in the value, and also in your select case don't use a space. i.e. do [value="Johannesburg"] and also do [case "Johannesburg":] and same for Pretoria. Hope you understand me? Keep me posted and cheers.

Comment: I changed it to "Johannesburg_Campus" and "Pretoria_Campus" on the form page and on the PHP code page.  I, email03, got it for both Johannesburg and Pretoria Campus.  Email04 for Pretoria campus informed me that she got the test info.  I'll let you know if email01 and email02 has received the test.  Once more thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Okay, at this stage email01 and email02 has not received the form content.  I and email04 received the form test almost immediately.  I don't know if there should be a time delay...

Comment: Did you send TWO tests? Because this form can only send to either (03 and 04) if Pretoria is checked, OR (01, 02, 03) if Joburg is checked. If only email03 and email04 got it, why not repeat the test for Joburg?

Comment: When I did the changes I did a test for both campuses. I did a Pretoria campus test - it was successful as it was delivered to me email03 and the person responsible for admissions in Pretoria email04.  The other test was for Johannesburg, here I email03 got the info, but email01 and email 02 didn't.

Comment: Ok thats odd, and its no longer about the script, something is wrong with the email config. There should not be a time delay. Did Hohannesburg 1 and 2 check their junk email box? Maybe their spam filter nicked it? They may need to add your sending email to an exclusion.

Comment: Even though I've selected JHB campus the info is sent to the Pretoria campus emails (email04 and mine, email03).  That is why the Johannesburg Campus isn't receiving the form.  Is there something else I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try using [value="Johannesburg"] and also do [case "Johannesburg":], no spaces, no underscores as you did e.g. dont do "Johannesburg_Campus". Try again, press Shift while reloading the page and test it. Feed me back.

Comment: Awesome, they got it this time.  Why didn't it want to go when I had the underscore in the name?  What happens when I press Shift while reloading the page?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: :) Im glad to be of help. It's weird but I guess the underscore gets converted to a hexadecimal ASCII code (%5F%) just like space becomes (%20%) as I explained before. See a chart for all ASCII characters here http://www.asciitable.com/ under the HEX column you will see the hexadecimal codes for each character. As for pressing Shift when reloading, that is in case your browser has cached the data from the server. Pressing Shift while reloading will make sure you are served the accurate online version of your page. Godspeed!

Answer (score 0):

in contact form in value field use email address like 
Which campus are you interested in?

```
<strong class="text_red">*</strong>
  <br>
      Johannesburg Campus:
      <input type="radio" name="Campus" value="johannesburg@aisj-jhb.com">
  <br>
      Pretoria Campus:
      <input type="radio" name="Campus" value="pretoria@aisj-jhb.com"><br></td>

then in action file write 
<?php $EmailTo = $_POST['Campus'];
?
```